# How does nginx ingress do url decoding?

Tags: nginx, urlencode

I have an url-encoded curl request to backend service which deployed in my k8s cluster. The request is proxied by nginx ingress before forwarding to pod running the service. By sniffering packets, I found that nginx ingress decoded the url. The same situation also described in this issue (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1615).

However, after encoding the request url twice, result shows nginx ingress did not decode the url. I wonder how does nginx ingress do url decoding? Does it only do decoding when the decoded result contains those characters needed to be encoded in url?